# Are any of the Steam achievements for Psychonauts missable?

Tags: steam, achievements, psychonauts

I've never played *Psychonauts* before, so I don't know how the game is structured (permanent linear progression or revistable chapters, for example). I'm playing the Steam version and I'd like to know if any of the achievements are missable when doing a single playthrough. I don't know which ones are tied to the narrative and which ones are possibly only for one-off occurrences that might be missable.

Comment: I am jealous of you. The Milkman Conspiracy is the best platformer level of all time.

Comment: There are definitely missable achievements.  [I beat the game with 12 of 37 achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/id/godrox3/stats/appid/3830/achievements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of easily missable achievements in Psychonauts. Most notably, there's a major point of no return when you rescue Lili, and several cutscenes/conversation achievements require that you go exploring in the campground between levels.

Honestly, your best bet is going to be to [use a guide](http://faqs.neoseeker.com/Games/PC/psychonauts_achievement.txt). The one linked helpfully hilights missable achievements, so you can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> through it to avoid spoilers.

Specifically, the following achievements are available anytime before the point of no return, however they are not missable so long as you see to them before taking that final step:

- **They Call Me The Hunter**
- **No Solid Food for Six Hours**
- **Stump Speech**
- **Camp Gossip**
- **A Slice of History**

Meanwhile, these other achievements must be completed at a specific opportunity:

- **I'm Gonna Live Forever** - in *Black Velevetopia*, be sure to collect the helmet from Dingo Inflagrante *before* helping Edward finish the card tower.
- **I Think They Were Impressed** -  Time limited achievement cutscene/conversation. Detailed in walkthrough.
- **Wolpow Says Thanks** -  Time limited achievement cutscene/conversation. Detailed in walkthrough.
- **Made Man** -  Time limited achievement cutscene/conversation. Detailed in walkthrough.
- **Maybe It's The Hair** -  -  Time limited achievement cutscene/conversation. Detailed in walkthrough.