# Do I get anything for the minigame at the beginning of Basic Braining - Obstacle Course 2?

Tags: psychonauts

I'm at the second part of the Basic Braining level and there's a minigame where I have to punch cardboard cutouts. I need to get a certain amount of points in X seconds. I've done the first few rounds and received Arrowheads for doing them, but I've failed one of the later ones a couple times now, and I'm wondering if I should just move on at this point.

Do I actually get anything else for going further in this minigame or is it just a way to grind out more Arrowheads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Funny you should mention it...](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124586/are-any-of-the-steam-achievements-for-psychonauts-missable)

You'll need to keep playing the Minigame until it's no longer available to achieve a perfect 'Rank 101' achievement. You'll also earn the "I LOVE PUNCHING" achievement.